# Is there a way to force C-protonation of an enolate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, reaction-control

[In another question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/48430/23444), I mentioned that O-protonation of an enolate followed by tautomerization may lead to increased amounts of the thermodynamic product over the kinetic product (when those are different species).

[The idea that the oxygen is likely protonated first has been discussed previously.](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/37224/23444)

The way, I think, to get the most kinetic product is to use a bulky acid that would do C-protonation rather than O-protonation (assuming sterics explain the difference in kinetic/thermo product). The proton would have to be a softer electrophile, i.e. less positively charged than a proton from a stronger acid.

To continue with the example I gave in the previous question, I think it's likely that C-protonation would look like this, where the major product would be the kinetic product:

[image]

So my question is: **are there acids that are known to specifically protonate the carbon of an enolate rather than the oxygen?** I was thinking maybe BHT would work. Or maybe the thiol analogue of BHT - yes, it would be more acidic than BHT, but it would also be a softer nucleofuge than the BHT anion. This reasoning works with alkyl halides, i.e. softer leaving group = more C-attack, but I'm not sure if the same goes here.

Comment: I guess $\sigma ^{*} _{\ce{S-H}}$ would be lower in energy than $\sigma ^{*} _{\ce{O-H}}$, so even though BHT would a weaker acid than the equivalent thiol, the thiol would still have better HOMO-LUMO overlap with carbon and lower $\delta +$ on the hydrogen.

Comment: I think it's reasonable to extend the logic of O- vs. C-alkylation to protonation. I don't see any good way of proving the results of the experiment though.

Comment: @jerepierre What do you mean you don't see any good way of proving the results? You mean that even if the results came out as I expected, it wouldn't be definitive that it happened the way I described it?

Comment: what technique would you use to prove that the oxygen or carbon is protonated first and the observed product is not the result of equilibration?

Comment: @jerepierre Probably nothing would *prove* it, but an increase in kinetic product would at least lend evidence to it. How about... Get it good and cold, then shoot in the deuterated you choose, wait a small period of time, then shoot in the non-deuterated acid and if you get purely deuterated material back, it means you did the deuteration without tautomerization (so C-deuteration), but if you get a mix, you probably still had some enol tautomer in there. This, of course, assumes that protonation/deureration is faster than tautomerization which may be naive of me.

Comment: Trap it as the silyl ketene acetal and then protonate that, eg. https://doi.org/10.1016/S0040-4039(00)84541-4

Comment: You might use tert-butyl bromide as your "acid" source via an E2 elimination.